# What changes to be done in Python file when Makefile is being used?

Tags: python, make

I have a set of python class files. I run the `MainProgram.py` on the linux as python `MainProgram.py` which uses the rest of the class files.It reads from an input file and write an output file.

Until now I have hardcoded the input path and output path in the program. But now I am supposed to use `makefile` mechanism to get a list of input paths and list of output paths.

How to write this `makefile`? How can I invoke this `makefile`? What corresponding changes has to be made in my python program to let it know that `makefile` is being used? After `makefile` is used how can I run my `python` program now?

Answer (score 1):

Makefile has almost nothing to do with your python program.  It really depends on what you want your makefile to do, but mostly you need to fix your python program to behave as it shoud (not just because of the Makefile but for general good practice).

A commandline script should normally take the input file as an argument (or from standard input, so that piping works), and write the output to stdout (or a file, specified as an argument). A normal invocation would then be something like

```
./MainProgram.py inputfile > outputfile
```

I assumed also that you use `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the first line to avoid calling the `python` interpreter explicitly every time you use it.

So... now that you have a program that takes an argument, you can freely write makefile rules. For instance, if your python file takes a `.a` file and creates a `.b` file from it, then you can write something like

```
.a.b:
    MainProgram.py $< > $@
```

for gnu make (the syntax may vary, there are different ways of doing things and some people will frown upon my way, but it's just an example). So... now you can just say

```
make foo.b
```

and it will call `MainProgram.py foo.a > foo.b` for you. You can then loop over files within the shell, or use Makefile for that too.

You can also make your main python program take an arbitrary number of arguments and do the work on all of them. Just like most core utilities (`wc` is one example).

I hope this answers your question - It's really unclear what you even need makefiles for. It seems unnecessary to me. Also, your program *shouldn't* care about who calls it... makefile or not, it should do what it is told to do. Tools should *always* be written so that they work well in all use cases.

Another thing... I do hope your file is not really named `MainProgram.py` :)

EDIT:

For files in multiple directories, try (example, so you get the idea):

```
find . -name '*.a' -exec ./MainProgram.py '{}' ';'
```

This calls your program for each file with the ending `.a`. No second argument is given, so the program will have to construct the output filename on its own. Or just make a wrapper shell script like

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$1"
output="${input%.*}.b"
./MainProgram.py "$input" "$output"
```

and use it instead of calling the python program directly. You see I just took the input file and replaced the extension. Again... this is just an example, I don't know what exactly you need.

Comment: The most typical way of handling most of such problems is to make your python program handle *one* file (unix philosophy, do one thing, and do it well). Then the wrapper should do the rest. If you have files in multiple directories, and are recognizable (by name, extension,...), use `find` with `-exec` parameter. I edited my answer.

Comment: The wrapper script is just to generate the output name from the input name, so that it is easier to call with `find`. The `find` command is just a way of looping over files - if they are all in the same directory, you can use a simple `for` loop, but if they are deeper in different directories, `find` is the best way.

Comment: How to run the wrapper Shell script?

Comment: Hey orion, I have a few more doubts. even though I add #!/usr/bin/env python, while running the program as just MainProgram.py , its showing error as command not found. Once I try ./MainProgram.py , the program is executing. I tried even chmod thing. Why is this? @orion

Comment: `chmod +x` makes these executable, so you can call them like that. You need `./` in front because you don't have `.` in your path, so the shell is not looking for the program there. People who run a lot of scripts from local directories, sometimes put `.` in the path, like `PATH="$PATH:."` so that you don't need to specify the current directory every time.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the paths (and other things...) in your python-program, you may want make use of argparse ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).  Being able to pass arguments to your program is often helpful when using `find ... -exec ...` as mentionned above.